# What are the options for traveling between Miri, Malaysia and Brunei?

Tags: public-transport, malaysia, brunei

We are a group of 6 people and we would like to travel from Miri to Bandar Seri Begawan in mid-August.

I have found that there exists a bus, but the times are a bit inconvenient for us. Is it possible to find some other ways of transfer directly at Miri?

Is it necessary to make reservation ahead of time for the bus, or is it enough to just show up at the bus stop?