# Options for traveling from Miri (Malaysia) to Bandar Seri Begawan (Brunei) in 2022

Tags: public-transport, borders, malaysia, borneo, brunei

After a long period of self-imposed COVID isolation, Brunei reopened to all travel on August 1, 2022.

I'm interested in traveling one way from Miri, Malaysia to Brunei's capital Bandar Seri Begawan (BSB), a distance of about 150 km.  In normal times, this is so easy that [a question asking about it was closed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98632/what-are-the-options-for-traveling-between-miri-malaysia-and-brunei); however, this time around:

- [There appear to be no public buses running](https://www.redbus.sg/bus-tickets/miri-to-brunei)
- It's usually possible to take a rental car across the border, but several local agencies I enquired with (Green Matrix, Epta, L&W) all said they can't do this now
- I've had no luck even with enquiries to taxis/private transfers

What are my options in <s>August</s> November 2022?  Is it feasible to take a Malaysian taxi to the border at Sg Tujoh, cross on foot and rent/take a Brunei taxi the rest of the way?

Comment: According to RedBus, the former operator on the route is [Bus Asia (Biaramas Express)](https://busasia.my/busasia/); they do not appear to have a public email address that I can find, but if all else fails, you could call them to ask when/if they plan to restart their Brunei service.

Comment: @mlc Thanks for the tip. I found their website at https://busasia.my, but there are no services to Brunei listed.

Comment: Any luck? We are planning to go to Brunei in September and we have not found anything yet.

Comment: @jmm No luck. Apparently the two different taxis approach is the only option for now.

Comment: Why not plane? (Sorry if it's a stupid question)

Comment: @DialFrost I don't think there are any flights, they're only 150km apart.

Comment: Sure there are!

Comment: @DialFrost Flightconnections.com doesn't find any, but if you find some operating now, please post an answer!

Comment: Oh if that website doesnt have that flight then does it mean there *won't* be any flights for it?

Comment: @DialFrost It's based on published schedules so it's pretty reliable.

Comment: @lambshaanxy So then theres no point posting an answer if there aint any flights :3

Comment: [Does this interest you?](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Miri/Bandar-Seri-Begawan)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140498/discussion-between-dialfrost-and-lambshaanxy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Miri to Sg Tujuh is only 30 km, so that's an easy and cheap taxi ride (or Grab, the Uber equivalent in Malaysia).

Cross the border on foot.  When bus services to run from Miri to BSB, passengers go through immigration on foot anyway, so this is nothing unusual.

Take a taxi (if you get lucky and one is waiting there) or use the Dart app (the Uber equivalent in Brunei) from Sg Tujuh to Kuala Belait, the nearest town with regular bus services to BSB.

Leave plenty of time due to customs and the transfers involved, and be ready to smile and ask nicely for help if there's a hiccup somewhere.  I don't think it will be much trouble.

Comment: Accepting this answer for now, but still open to updates/new answers re: scheduled buses, cross-border taxis, rentals, etc if/when they materialize.