# Bandar Seri Begawan to Kota Kinabalu

Tags: transportation, borneo, brunei

We are trying to get into and out of Brunei without flying, similar to [Options for traveling from Miri (Malaysia) to Bandar Seri Begawan (Brunei) in 2022](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175311/options-for-traveling-from-miri-malaysia-to-bandar-seri-begawan-brunei-in-20?noredirect=1&lq=1).

We want to go in from Miri and out to Kota Kinabalu. It appears that the route from Miri is straightforward (I assume that worked for @lambshaanxy), but all of our research indicates that we can take a bus or taxi from Limbang (Malaysia). However, how do we get there?

Comment: The mentioned question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175311/options-for-traveling-from-miri-malaysia-to-bandar-seri-begawan-brunei-in-20 (and I ended up not going in part because I couldn't figure out reasonable transport)

Comment: It's *Bandar Seri Begawan

Answer (score 2):

The best way I can think of is to give Limbang a pass, and take two ferries: Muara to Labuan (and do some duty-free shopping!), and then Labuan to KK. See the schedules [here](https://www.pulaulabuan.com/ferry-schedules/).

Comment: This is a very cool route and not even that expensive! (25 sgd to reach Labuan)

Comment: @Jochem Indeed! Before Covid Labuan had a flight to Brunei, but it wasn't financially viable. The ferry is fast enough, and real cheap.